# Is there an exhaustive list of mobile browser issues similar to what we have in the desktop space?

Tags: html, cross-browser, mobile-website

I've been doing a lot of mobile web development lately and two things have really shocked me: The number of browser-specific bugs (and shortcomings) and the complete lack of documentation on these bugs when I search online.  I could avoid a lot of them simply by rejecting Android 2.1 and iOS 3 devices and that may make sense a year from now but they still represent a large enough chunk of the market that I really need to support them.

Right now I'm using http://www.caniuse.com where I can but this only tells me about missing HTML5 features not about bugs.  Also, if I want to read deeper into what "partial support" means, I have to click through to the websites it links to which may or may not contain the information.

These are a few bugs and differences (maybe not bugs but something developers should be aware of) I've identified:

- Android 2.1 doesn't prevent clicking on elements covered by an overlay element.
- Android 2.1 doesn't always clear `placeholder` text immediately (sometime visibly, sometimes invisibly) counting against `maxlength`.
- Android 2.1 HTC desn't fire touchend events if scrolling occurs.
- Android 2.1 (ans sometime iOS3) may prevent all in-page network connections after application cache download finishes.
- Android 2.1 supports `background-size` only through `-webkit-background-size`.
- Android 2.1 and iOS 3 do not have correct styling for HTML5 elements.
- On Android devices, `inline-block` elements will sometime exceed their specified widths and overflow to the next line: 33.33% + 33.33% + 33.33% > 100%
- iOS 3 may blank out elements during translate3D or tranlateX transitions.
- Android 2.2 (one device) would occasionally render the new page's 3D translated elements on top of the old page during page navigation.

Each of these bugs required a significant amount of testing, experimentation, and often-futile research.  I'm sure there is a lot of collective knowledge on these device- and version-specific problems but I haven't seen it channeled into websites like we have for the desktop.  Does anyone know of any sites out there that have this?

Comment: Did this work?  I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/) does have a list of many mobile browsers and what is and isn't included.

Comment: I've tried QuirksMode but most of its mobile content is really old, doesn't cover different browser versions, and doesn't cover bugs.  Its mostly just an overview of what you could expect to be there and not how it will perform.